# Cassandra DB: store binary file record via shell

Tags: shell-script, cassandra

While the dev team works on a REST service to manage binary data in Cassandra, ops would like to store local blobs directly from shell.

Is it actually possible via CQL/bash without a Cassandra driver? I could find so far only an [example for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056494/how-to-store-binary-data-with-cassandra-cql).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do it with cqlsh is wrap binary file into CSV file and run `cqlsh --some_args -e 'COPY table_name FROM binary_wrapped.csv'`, but in order to do so you have to generate a new primary key to use in CSV-file.

IMO: Since cqlsh is a wrapper around python client, your ops should just write simple python script for this operation, it would be much easier in many ways.